# Substitute Cell References in Function, not Resultant String

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a complicated formula that I would like to use in a table, while charting the effects of changing one cell in the formula.

```
=($E$9+J2)-((($B$9+J2)+($B$23*200*$B$15)+(1E+99-1)*(($B$9+J2)*(1.1+(1-$B$23)*(0.75+($B$22*$B$15*0.4))*$B$15)+($B$23*200*$B$15)+$B$23*(FLOOR.MATH(1E+99/3)*200*$B$15/MAX(1,1E+99-1))))*$B$12/1E+99)*($E$9+J2)/((($E$9+J2)+($E$23*200*$E$15)+(1E+99-1)*(($E$9+J2)*(1.1+(1-$E$23)*(0.75+($E$22*$E$15*0.4))*$E$15)+($E$23*200*$E$15)+$E$23*(FLOOR.MATH(1E+99/3)*200*$E$15/MAX(1,1E+99-1))))*$E$12/1E+99)
```

As you can see, there are some repeating functions that I attempted to simplify with substitute.

```
=($E$9+J2)-SUBSTITUTE($B$29,$B$9,($B$9+J2))*$E$9/SUBSTITUTE($E$29,$E$9,($E$9+J2))
```

This doesn't work because substitute is actually converting the **result** of the functions into strings and searching for instances rather than converting the function itself.

If we were programming in a computer language, we could simply call on a method with different arguments, but I'm not sure if excel is capable of doing this.

====

To illustrate the challenge in this "simplified" spreadsheet, I have two formulas

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  | 
1 |    1   101   202      
2 |  100
```

Cell B1 has this formula

```
=A1+A2
```

and Cell C1 has this formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,A1*2)
```

I want cell C1 to be 102 instead of 202. Is there a way to substitute each instance of A1 in the formula rather than the resulting string?

Comment: What is your goal here? Why are you substituting at all? You are working with numbers to begin with, why no simple math?

Comment: Are you looking for this formula? *=B1-A1+SUBSTITUTE(A1,A1,A1*2)*

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified exactly why I attempted to use substitute rather than oversimplifying the problem. I'm trying to chart a table using similar functions f(x) & f'(x) and and I want to find a function that will allow me to call on the functions within the cell rather than type them explicitly, which could result in "runtime errors". It's a common problem in programming that is caused by copying and pasting code to make small edits, rather than using methods/functions.

Comment: If you have the latest version of Excel / O365 you should have access to the `LET` function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Is there any way I can separate the variables from the formula, i.e. similar to LET(x, A1*2, y, A2, B2) where B2 = x+y?

Comment: I think the closest would be something like `=LET(x,A1*2,y,A2,x+y)`.  If you need to parse out the formula in B2, you'd probably need to write a formula parser in VBA. But it might be simpler to just write the whole formula as a VBA UDF instead.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Your method should help me avoid copy paste errors at least. I'm not sure I want to learn VBA just for this project. If you want to post the answer and get credit for it I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have the most recent version of Excel (I don't), one simple solution that often works, but hard to say in your's without seeing more is to add a helper column somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest approximation of what you want, based on what you show in your comments, would be something like

`=LET(x,A1*2,y,A2,x+y)`.

If you need to parse out the formula in B2, you'd probably need to write a formula parser in VBA. But it might be simpler to just write the whole formula as a VBA UDF instead.

*Note: `LET` is only available in the latest versions of Excel O365*

Comment: +1 When I saw that long formula I immediately thought of LET function. Can you just mention in your answer that it is only available for Excel 365 ?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I had mentioned it in my comments and neglected to repeat that in the answer. Tks for the heads-up.